# Linked questions security vs. transparency.

Tags: discussion

So sometimes I ask security questions, e.g. questions about sql-injection.  And sometimes I ask questions about security configuration that are made easier to solve by linking to the site that I'm working on.

Unfortunately, this makes generally identifiable the site that has a security problem.

Rediculous example:

> Q: My site has a sql-injection problem
>   where if you pass the param:
>   ?obliterate=1 it drops the database,
>   how do I deal with this?

and:

> Q: My site at example.com doesn't have
>   the right apache config, blah, blah,
>   blah.

How should I deal with that linkage issue?  Anyone else considered that and come to a conclusion they'd like to share?

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that the first question is a programming issue (you need to sanitize your input), so is off topic for SF.

Answer (score 4):

I just plain never reveal the actual URL of the server or any other non-public information. I carefully strip IPs, DNS, and internal server names from my examples/questions/answers/etc. I even do so for other people Q&A at times, especially if it's isn't 100% necessary to resolving the question.

I highly recommend figuring out how to ask question without divulging this information, though it's your choice (and opens you up to the problems you cited).

Comment: I do the same except for RFC 1918 addresses.

Comment: I use [RFC 5737](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5737) addresses when I remember to do so.

Comment: @Chris S - Wow, another day, another RFC learned that I had never seen before. Thanks!